# method resolution order MRO

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

Why after searching B, it does not go deeper to search Y OR z but go to search A?

Y is the parent of A, if should search A first, but Y is the parent of B so it should search Y first, why this does not throw a MRO error?

Can someone explain how this lookup works?

```
class X(object):pass
class Y(object): pass
class Z(object): pass
class A(X,Y): pass
class B(Y,Z):pass
class M(B,A,Z):pass
print M.__mro__
```

gives

```
(<class '__main__.M'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.Y'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <type 'object'>)
```

[image]

Comment: That is standard [C3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, after searching `B`, we can't consider `Y` immediately because it is a child of `A`. We can't consider `Z` immediately because `M` inherits from `A` *before* it inherits from `Z`.

---

Python uses C3 method resolution order [details here](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) .

C3 resolution order solves the diamond inheritance problem well

In the example below, we have a very generic class `Object` that's a superclass of `B` and `C`. We only want method implementations (say of `__repr__` or something) in `Object` to be considered if neither `B` nor `C` have an implementation.

```
         Object
         /   \
        B     C
         \   /
           A
```

In other words, each possible parent in the *transitive closure* of the parent classes of `A` is considered, but the classes are ordered according to the "latest" path from the base class to the class in question.

There are two paths to `object`:

```
A -> B -> Object
A -> C -> Object
```

The "latest" path is `A -> C -> Object` because `A -> B -> Object` would be earlier in a left-biased depth-first search.

C3 linearization satisfies two key invariants:

- if `X` inherits from `Y`, `X` is checked before `Y`.
- if `Z` inherits from `U` and then `V` *in that order*, `U` is checked before `V`.

Indeed `C3` linearization guarantees that both of those properties hold.

It's possible to construct hierarchies that can't be linearized, in which case you get an exception at class definition time.

running `inherit.py`

```
class E: pass      
class F: pass
class A(E, F): pass
class B(F, E): pass
class Z(A, B): pass
```

produces the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inherit.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Z(A, B): pass
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases E, F
```

Comment: Would you please speak to the example I give?@Gregory Nisbet?  what is the reason that after checking B, it checks A instead of Y? After reading your explanation my understanding is: A inherits from X and Y, so we have to check A, not Y, is it?

Comment: @Lisa ... Yes. We have to delay checking `Y` because `A` inherits from `Y` as well.  classes with multiple inheritance paths to them are checked as late as possible.

Comment: @Lisa Think of it this way: `M` is "more" like `A` because it inherits from `A` directly, unlike `Y`, which is only inherited indirectly (via `B` and `A`), which means we'd like to use a method definition from `A` in preference to one from `Y`.

Comment: @chepner I may be misinterpreting your comment, but it seems to suggest that we're traversing the inheritance hierarchy in a breadth first manner to look for method implementations, which isn't how C3 works.

Comment: I just wanted to provided some intuition for *why* C3 puts `A` before `Y`. (Although, does C3 devolve to BFS as long as you never explicitly inherit from one of your parent's ancestors? Ten whole second's thought didn't provide a counterexample :))

Comment: @chepner ... C3 devolves to DFS if we're in a tree. If `A < B, C` and `B < D < E` ... then we will check `A, B, D, E, C`. With the notation `X < P1, P2` meaning `X` inherits from `P1` and then `P2`.

Comment: Ah, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118463/1126841) gives an example where C3 diverges from breadth-first, for reasons my comment doesn't cover.